# Using complex variables in django templates

Tags: django, templates, dictionary

In the template below, user.group is a number and it has to be shown as **group_name.get(user.group)** Are there any ability to pass to template **group_name** dict and use **group_name.get(user.group)** inside template?

```
<table>
{% for user in users %}
<tr>    
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.group}}</td>
</tr> 
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of django this logic should live in the code, not in the template. Can't you add a method `user.get_group()` that returns the group?

Answer (score 0):

No, the dot notation doesn't allow for looking up names by variable value.

I would do this in the view, if it's specific to this one template.

```
for user in users:
    users.group_name = group_name.get(user.group)


{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.group_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

If it's applicable to all users, do as jammon suggested and define a method on `User`

Out of curiosity, can I see your models? Just curious why group is a number and where `group_name` comes from.